# Building a DCount/SQL statement in VBA via concetenation if test is true

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a data entry form (Access 2007) which is designed to find out if the captured animal already has an existing WHno.  Unfortunately, the data is messy and these is not a single unique identifier so several tests must be performed to narrow the search.

The animal could have 1 to 10 different pieces of information which will help identify the animal’s existence in the database. (The script only tests for about half of them thus far) I was thinking the best way to do this would to be to “build” a DCount and/or SQL statement based on which fields the user selects. I hope test to see if a particular text field box (unbound) has been filled out, and if yes, concatenate that section of code to the DCount/SQL statement, then move on to the next text field box to test.

Once the statement has been completely built, I want to test to see how many records have been counted/selected. If one record has been selected, I want to display the results in FormA. If 2 or more records are found, I want to display the records in a multi-listing form (FormB) from which the user can select the correct animal based on additional information not tested but displayed in FormB. If zero records are found, I want to create a new record with the data entered into the form updated into the table.

The hurdle I am struggling with now is building the DCount statements. I keep getting syntax errors . I do not know how to put this together piecemeal when the function bombs out because the syntax is incomplete (which it will be until I finish “building” it.)

I know the data is a mess. The scene out in the field is chaotic, different people gather different kinds of information, and not all the data that should be entered on the paper forms get filled out completely - if at all. The data gathering procedures are unlikely to change anytime soon.

Ideas? A different but easier approach idea is also welcome. New to this and not sure of all my programming options.

Also, how long can this statement be before it bombs out?

Code so far:

```
Private Sub GenerateWHno_Click()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

If IsNull(Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtSpecies) Or (Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtSpecies) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Species is a required field. Please enter a species"
    Exit Sub

End If


MsgBox txtSpecies

' Each line of code below indicates a data entry field(s) that needs testing and appended to SpeciesCount if "true". The first line is unchanging and is declared upfront.

'SpeciesCount = DCount("[Species]", "AnimalInfo", "(nz([Status])= '' OR [Status] = 'Alive' OR [Status] = 'Unknown') AND ([Species]= '" & txtSpecies & "')" _
'    & "AND (((nz([L_ET_Color1])= '" & Nz(txtL_ET_Color1) & "' AND nz([L_ET_No1])= '" & nz(txtL_ET_No1) & "')" _
'    & "AND (((nz([R_ET_Color1])= '" & Nz(txtR_ET_Color1) & "' AND nz([R_ET_No1])= '" & nz(txtR_ET_No1) & "')" _
'    & "AND nz([L_ET_No2])= '" & nz(txtL_ET_No2) & "')" _
'    & "AND nz([R_ET_No2])= '" & nz(txtR_ET_No2) & "')" _
'    & "")


'If txtL_ET_Color Is Not Null Or txtL_ET_No Is Not Null Then
    'LET1 = & "AND (((nz([L_ET_Color1])= '" & Nz(txtL_ET_Color1) & "' AND nz([L_ET_No1])= '" & nz(txtL_ET_No1) & "')" _
    'Species Count = SpeciesCount & LET1
'End If

'If txtR_ET_Color Is Not Null Or txtR_ET_No Is Not Null Then
    'RET1 = & "AND (((nz([R_ET_Color1])= '" & Nz(txtR_ET_Color1) & "' AND nz([R_ET_No1])= '" & nz(txtR_ET_No1) & "')" _
    'Species Count = SpeciesCount & RET1
'End If

'If txtL_ET_No2 Is Not Null Then
    'LET2 = AND nz([L_ET_No2])= '" & nz(txtL_ET_No2) & "')" _
'Species Count = SpeciesCount & LET2
'End If

'If txtR_ET_No2 Is Not Null Then
    'RET2 = AND nz([R_ET_No2])= '" & nz(txtR_ET_No2) & "')" _
'Species Count = SpeciesCount & RET2
'End If

'There are about 4 more options/fields to add to the script but you get the idea.

'Thus: If user selected Species, and filled out L_ET_Color1 and/or L_ET_No1, the final concatenation (DCount statement)would look like this:
SpeciesCount = DCount("[Species]", "AnimalInfo", "([Status]= 'Alive' OR [Status] = 'Unknown' OR nz([Status]) = '') AND [Species]= '" & txtSpecies & "' AND (nz([L_ET_Color1])= '" & Nz(txtL_ET_Color1) & "' AND nz([L_ET_No1])= '" & Nz(txtL_ET_No1) & "')")

    If SpeciesCount > 1 Then
        MsgBox SpeciesCount & " Greater than 1. Please select correct animal"
        'Create SQL statement that mimics DCount statement and display all fields from AnimalInfo table as multilisting to select from

    ElseIf SpeciesCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You need a new WHno"

        WHno = Nz(DMax("WHno", "AnimalInfo")) + 1
        MsgBox WHno

        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("AnimalInfo")
            rs.AddNew
            rs!WHno = WHno
            rs!Species = txtSpecies
            rs!L_ET_Color1 = txtL_ET_Color1
            rs!L_ET_No1 = txtL_ET_No1
            rs.Update
            rs.Close
    Else
        'Create SQL statement that mimics DCount statement and display all fields from AnimalInfo table as single listing in a form.
        MsgBox "You're WHno is " & WHno & " Is this the correct WHno?"
    End If
    Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtSpecies = ""
    Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtL_ET_Color1 = ""
    Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtL_ET_No1 = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to first compose the condition into a string variable. There you can print its content via Debug.Print and see what the problem might be.

If you cannot spot the problem via inspection alone, paste the generated string to the Sql view of a proper query and see if Access gives you helpful information on switching to design view.

Comment: The following article explains how to dynamically build SQL/DCount statements: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html in better detail.